# Preload rails scope with STI and has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following association

```
subscription.rb
belongs_to :plan
has_many :consumer_goods, through: :plan


product.rb
# STI model 
# ConsumerGood < Product

has_and_belongs_to_many :plans, -> { distinct }, foreign_key: :product_id
scope :active, -> {where(state: :active)}
scope :released,
lambda {
  joins(:plans).merge(active).where.not(plans: { id: plan_id_param }).distinct
}


plan.rb
has_many :subscriptions

has_and_belongs_to_many :products, -> { distinct }

has_and_belongs_to_many :consumer_goods
```

I'm attempting to accomplish the following.

```
subscription.rb
belongs_to :plan
has_many :consumer_goods, through: :plan

has_many :released_consumer_goods, {merge(ConsumerGood.released)}, class_name: 'XX', source: 'XX'
```

So i can preload this scope like `Subscription.includes(:released_consumer_goods)`.

However i'm unable to get the syntax right for this.